# add extra fields to a brightway activity from an existing database

Tags: brightway

I want to store information in some activities that are modified versions of activities imported from an existing database (ecoinvent).

I know we can add fields to activities created *from scratch* [(example)](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2/raw/default/notebooks/Activities%20and%20exchanges.ipynb). (I guess this is because the structure of the database has not yet been defined...) but is there a way of adding it to activities of an already defined database without breaking it?

The way around I found is to add entries to the *author* dict, which I can easily access later on. e.g.

```
act['author']['scenario']='myscenario'
```

but I admit it is not a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add whatever data you want. Brightway is a (semi-)[schemaless database](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/intro.html#activity-data-format) for exactly this reason.

```
act['foo'] = 'bar'
act.save()
```

Comment: that's embarrassingly simple, I swear I got an error trying to do this. I think it was doing act['new_stuff']={} and then act['new_stuff]['foo']='bar' but actually with the _update_ method it works.